# How to view a full disk data (more than one partition) cloned with dd

Tags: linux, hard-drive, clone, dd, iso

I've a disk image done with dd:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/fulldisk.img
```

`/dev/sda` have some partitions (Windows+Linux)

My problem is: I need to know if the image is done well, how can I access data? (especially Linux data)

I've tried with Windows utilities like ext2explorer or directly mounting the image, but I cannot access data.

Is there a way to do it (with Windows or Linux)?

Comment: Can you post the command and the error you got when you tried this?

Comment: There's no error (i'm trying to mount it in windows), simply, don't do nothing, when I try other ways i get some 'data corrupted' message (but i think that's the system get some raw data that it cannot undestand.

Comment: Did you try to mount it under Linux? Linux can understand Windows partitions as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux you can use `kpartx`. First see with `kpartx -l /mnt/fulldisk.img` to see if it can recognize the partition layout. If it can, `kpartx -a /mnt/fulldisk.img` makes your partitions available under `/dev/mapper/loop0pX` where `X` is partition number.

You can then mount those partitions with

`mount -o loop /dev/mapper/loop0pX /some/mount/point`

Just replace `X` with your desired partition number.

After you are finished, use `umount /some/mount/point` and `kpartx -d /mnt/fulldisk.img` to properly disconnect your disk image.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There's a way to do it under windows also? With linux, I've found also those method: get and calculate the offset of the partition and mount using: mount -o loop,offset=xxx image /mnt but it seems a very raw option...

Answer (score 2):

All recent kernels (it was added somewhere around 2.6.2x) support partition tables on loop devices. Only the default is to disable this.

`modinfo loop` should give you information whatever it supports a `max_part` parameter.
If it does, add to `modprobe.conf`

```
options loop max_part=16
```

and do `rmmod loop` and `modprobe loop` (all loop devices must be unused for it to work). This way, when mounting a single image using a loop device, all partitions will be automatically available:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 /mnt/fulldisk.img
mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/part1
mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt/part2
```